# Jenkins' homepage loading very slowly

Tags: deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I setup a Jenkins server and created about 1,000 jobs. The problem I have is it takes roughly 5 minutes to load its homepage while takes less than 30 seconds to load other page (for example, configuration page)

What is the reason of this problems? Is there anyway to fix them?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new view with fewer jobs and set that to be your default view.

If you get the [Status View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Status+View+Plugin) plugin, you can add all jobs to it, and filter by status "Failed".  This gives you a view that you can call "All Failed" and it does very well as a default view.

Unless, of course, you have 1000 failed jobs..

Comment: I installed the plugin but couldn't find the option to filter by failed jobs.

Comment: It's in the Edit View configuration page.